# should apps be deployed to an ESB?

Tags: wso2, soa, apache-servicemix

I have just watched a youtube WSO2 [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KXKppaOgtY&feature=plcp) where two common mistakes are discussed (15m 17s):

1. Do not use a broker in place of a service container by hosting business logic
2. Do not use a broken in place of a process coordinator by hosting coordination logic

This makes sense for the WSO2 product set, where there are difference products for each concern.

However, from what I can tell from camel/servicemix mailing lists, it is common to combine servicemix (or fuseesb) + camel + activiti for the three concerns of (a) enterprise integration, (b) hosting business logic and (c) hosting coordination logic.  To avoid the mistakes listed above, should I create separate servicemix instances to separate the concerns? For example:

1. Servicemix standalone as a service container for business logic (e.g. osgi applications)
2. Servicemix + camel as a broker
3. Servicemix + activiti as a process coordinator

I guess the answer will depend on transaction volumes.  Very large transaction volumes warrant logically separating the concerns, whereas it will probably be ok to mix the concerns into a single deployment for smaller transaction volumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I guess you have provided the answer your self :)

It certainly depend on the load. Basically each use-case is different from the other. If you expect high load for you broker, its better to isolate the broker and use it just for the brokering, same goes for others. WSO2 stack is simply providing the answer separating these concerns properly. Even with WSO2 you can create a single carbon instance with all these feature. but not advised :)

Regards,
/Nuwan